# Weird ssh key fingerprint .lan

Tags: networking, macos, ssh

After generating a new rsa ssh key with passphrase using Terminal and ssh-keygen on Mac OSX El Capitan, I get the following message (personal info redacted:

The key fingerprint is:

00:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff myuser@myLaptop.lan

I'm wondering why I'm getting .lan at the end of the User parameter. I'm guessing it stands for Local Area Network, but I've never seen it appended to my user login.

Answer (score 2):

The .lan, which does stand for "local area network", is a [pseudo-top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-top-level_domain) sometimes used as a default domain name for Microsoft Windows Active directory [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) that aren't accessible from the Internet via a [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). I've seen it used with Windows Small Business Server (SBS) 2003 [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain). Also see answers to the question [What's the difference between .local, .home, and .lan?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92441/whats-the-difference-between-local-home-and-lan) at the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site where [.local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local), another pseudo-top-level domain, is also mentioned.

Apple's [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) implementation of [zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) uses .local, so I would more likely expect .local than .lan on your OS X system. E.g., see the Apple support article [Mac OS X v10.4, 10.5, 10.6: How to look up ".local" hostnames via both Bonjour and standard DNS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201275) which mentions:

> The Multicast DNS feature of Bonjour allows devices on a local network
>   to connect to each other without a separate DNS server by using the
>   ".local" domain, as described in this
>   [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20999).

As for why you are seeing it on your OS X system, if you try `nslookup mylaptop.lan` do you see a locally assigned IP address for your laptop. Are you on a network with Microsoft Windows systems?